# How to add "description" to a Filament Laravel List Page? (Show some text below the Title)

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-filament

[Here it is the place where i want to place the text on an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7J1b.png)

In the picture you can appreciate the place where i want to show some text, that might be like a simple but good looking <p> tag.
Im using Laravel 10, PHP 8 and Filament V2.

I know it looks kinda dumb but i sincerely havent found something to do it.
Im kinda a beginner and this is my first filament app.
Just some description of the resource is that i want to show.

If you can get at least a similar result it would be very nice of you!!!
Really hope you can help me out, ill be very thankful to you.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Post _all_ relevant code/your full attempt, example data, expected result from that data and what currently happens (we need details, incl. full error messages, if any.) Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that was recommended to you when you registered.

Comment: I feel like it is pretty straight forward, i want to add text below Title of List Page of Filament Resource... 
I dont have errors nor attemps as Filament Pages are more like a config task rather than a programming one, i just dont know how to do it and havent found anything on the documentation.

Comment: _"I feel like it is pretty straight forward"_ - Well, I apparently didn't, or I wouldn't have asked for some actually useful information. I'm not in the habit of trying to waste peoples time with unnecessary questions. Please read the links I posted in my previous comment to learn how to improve your question, making it easier (or even possible) for us to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
protected ?string $subheading = 'This is the subheading.';
```

You'd need to add this to your Pages\List class for the resource in question.